# Twitter : Encountered error with status code: 404

Tags: error-handling, twitter

I'm working on a project that involves accessing the Twitter API streaming functionality. However, I keep encountering an error with status code 404 when trying to access the API. I have checked my code, verified the permissions and I'm still unable to resolve the issue.
Is there anything specific I should be aware of or additional steps I can take to troubleshoot this problem? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error.

Thank you in advance for your help!